# Designing a verticle scrollbar with style in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

It may be a very easy to do or very tough, but can anyone please suggest to me how design a `scrollviewer` like this image[image: Vertical scroll viewer]

In the design field I am pretty new in WPF. I come to know about this design in Visual studio Blend 2013 and like this UI look and feel, please suggest a way to code for it in xaml or in code behind in the UI.

This is my approach for the thumbs

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Fill="Transparent" />
                    <Border x:Name="Rectangle1" CornerRadius="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Background="LightGray" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
                        <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Height" Value="7" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But how to change the up-down arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for the work, I did it with help of  [This site](http://netprogrammingodyssey.wordpress.com/2010/08/21/styling-the-silverlight-scrollbar-control-like-blend/)

[image: Image from original answer webpage]

- **Answer repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/JuanMejiaVelez/WordPressSamples)**.

and the style I put into a resources and using wherever I want. For others who might be needing the code to work please follow the procedures described in the link and you are done.

Answer (score 5):

I can give you sample for the scrollbar I incorporated recently in my one sample project but I did not want thumb inside it. So, you might want to tweak a bit of sample.

Here is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                    <Rectangle
                        Width="Auto"
                        Height="Auto"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Fill="Transparent" />
                    <Border
                        x:Name="ScrollBarRectangle"
                        Width="Auto"
                        Height="Auto"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="5" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
                        <Setter TargetName="ScrollBarRectangle" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ScrollBarRectangle" Property="Height" Value="7" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-5,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF8C8C8C" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid
                    x:Name="GridRoot"
                    Width="8"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Track
                        x:Name="PART_Track"
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsDirectionReversed="true">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb
                                x:Name="ScrollBarThumb"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                Style="{StaticResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                        </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton
                                x:Name="PageUp"
                                Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand"
                                Focusable="false"
                                Opacity="0" />
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton
                                x:Name="PageDown"
                                Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand"
                                Focusable="false"
                                Opacity="0" />
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="ScrollBarThumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                        <Setter TargetName="GridRoot" Property="LayoutTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="LayoutTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="8" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ScrollBarThumb" Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PageDown" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PageUp" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the design, but in this template the up-down arrow keys are not visible in the UI. I have seen in the code RepeatButton is present but Up-Down arrows are missing any idea how can i make it display?