# How can I make my ScrollViewer Vertical ScrollBar always be visibile?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a style for a ScrollViewer and I want the vertical scrollbar to be visible even when there is no content to scroll but I can't seem to get it to work. From what I've found on previous questions is that all you need to do is set VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Visible but it still hides that way. What am I missing here?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Color x:Key="BorderColor">#a9aba9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ThumbColor">#868786</Color>

    <Style x:Key="PropertiesUCScrollViewer"
           TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
                Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                              MaxWidth="15" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                BorderThickness="0.25"
                                Margin="15 0 0 0">
                            <ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />
                        </Border>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Style="{DynamicResource PropertiesUCScrollBar}"
                                   Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                   Visibility="Visible"
                                   Width="1" />
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Style="{DynamicResource PropertiesUCScrollBar}"
                                   Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                   Visibility="Collapsed" />

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="PropertiesUCScrollBarThumb"
           TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable"
                Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="3"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Width="8" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PropertiesUCVerticalScrollBar"
                     TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Border CornerRadius="2"
                    Background="Transparent" />

            <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   IsDirectionReversed="true">
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource PropertiesUCScrollBarThumb}">
                        <Thumb.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ThumbColor}" />
                        </Thumb.BorderBrush>
                        <Thumb.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ThumbColor}" />
                        </Thumb.Background>
                    </Thumb>
                </Track.Thumb>

            </Track>

        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="PropertiesUCScrollBar"
           TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="True" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation"
                     Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Height"
                        Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Template"
                        Value="{StaticResource PropertiesUCVerticalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply set the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property to `ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled`?

Comment: As far as I can tell that makes the Scrollbar always invisible, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, you are right. i misread your question and though you want to disable the vertical bar. Then simply set the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property to `ScrollBarVisibility.Visible`.

Answer (score 0):

When the content is fit to the container the height of scroll thumb in theory is Zero. So what the user can see is scrollbar **Track**.
So beside of setting *Scrollbar* visibility to "*visible*", what you should do is setting the **background color** of the Track.
Here is a mockup and [link to a scrollbar style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22062086/8359674) which you can check for yourself:

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
 <Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollBar">
       <!-- You Can set the Track Background Color -->
       <Track Name="PART_Track"  Background="Red">
         <!-- ... -->
         <Track.Thumb>
           <!--You Can set the height of the Thumb.-->
           <Thumb Height="30"/>
         </Track.Thumb>
       </Track>
       <!-- ... -->
     </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```